# Regex: Use a string structure, excluding capital letters

Tags: regex

I would like to match a string with the following structure string1-string2-string3 where each string can include numerics but no capital letters.

a concrete example would be "hello-world-today"

I have a regex expression, but I am sure it's not optimal since I repeat the same pattern three times.

`'([a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)-(([a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?))-(([a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?))'`

Comment: You can even achieve it with just one group by forcing an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) hyphen by use of a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): [`^(?:[a-z\d]+-?\b)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/PRkNGu/1) - Replace `+` (*one or more*) at end with the desired [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) for repititions, e.g. [`{2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/UaZYNF/1) for *two or more* or [`{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/krsM4X/2) for *exactly three*.

Answer (score 0):

This should be an effective way:

```
^(?:[a-z\d]+-){2}([a-z\d]+)$
```

It matches two groups of lowercase letters and numbers followed by a dash and then another group of the same characters without the dash at the end.